# Running Gradle task error (Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I really need help.
I encounter this problem when I want to run the project.

No matter what I did, the problem was not solved.

I did

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get
```

but it still didn't work

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA6t1.jpg)

What should I do now?

I don't have any idea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bt7rb.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbEov.jpg)

Comment: Please don't post error output and stack traces as screenshot, that makes it very difficult to read. Just copy and pasted the text into your question and format it as code.

Answer (score -1):

go to terminal and run this code to get the detailed error

```
flutter run -v
```

then comment me the first error in red you get.

Comment: [  +48 ms] Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.

Comment: Looks like you are running flutter run command from a different directory (maybe parent directory).

Try running flutter run command from the project directory.

Comment: Launching lib\main.dart on SM A105F in debug mode... is it false??

Comment: well this looks like the the project directory go to the project terminal and run flutter run -v

Comment: [   +2 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
what should I do ?

Comment: take a screenshot of the whole error after running flutter run -v

Comment: where can i send ?

Comment: upload it in your question

Comment: I'm uploaded the image

Comment: bro you see in the terminal there's 4 pages problems and Output and Debug Console and Terminal click on that terminal then type down flutter run -v then show me the result